# Static Values are not visible in separate jars

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

In my web application- ear, A value of static varialble located in a jar called "A" is changed in ear . That newly changed value is visible and retains as it is. But whenever that variablel is accessed in another jar called "B", the updated value is not available, and first initialized value is only available.  I use JBoss and jars are in tomcat-sar folder. 
 For example:

// Default Ajar's static variable status;

```
 Ajar.Aclass.staticVariableA = "initializedValue";  

inside my utility classes in ear, Ajar.Aclass.staticVariableA = "NewValue";
```

// Then, when Bjar which is located in war also now access the Ajar's static variable,

```
 System.out.println("value in B jar : " + Ajar.Aclass.staticVariableA );
```

// This prints  *value in B jar : initializedValue*

As I feel, the value of A.jar is valid in ear context as it is initialized inside the ear. B.jar has its own context and whenever variables in A.jar is called, those variables'initial value is returned.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: The obvious question is: why do you want this?

Comment: This must be the same JVM, java executable, the same web application (the same classloader, which separates an X class for another X class in another web appl). In general use a bean in the application, a servlet init parameter or whatever.

Comment: Where are jars A & B deployed relative to the WAR? If they are both in the same WEB-INF/lib directory they will share the same class loader.

Comment: @SteveC. Thanks for your answer. They are not in the web-inf/lib, but same location where my all jars in JBoss. I am not clear "Where are jars A & B deployed relative to the WAR " ?  Actually my applicaion is ear and deployed in deploy folder. Jars are in apache-tomcat-sar.

Comment: You're going to have to research the class loading (and configuration thereof) model that the version of JBossAS that you're using utilises.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross-context servletContext attributes as straight forward approach

But to answer your question, because you already have progressed using static variables

**Warning: as per JAVA's offical documentation, using reflection should be carefully done, such a way that you do not manipulate inaccessible objects**

Put the following crossContext="true" inside TOMCAT_HOME\conf\context.xml

```
<Context crossContext="true">
```

And you have to load the Class via ServletContext and ClassLoader Methodology

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
ServletContext othercontext = context.getContext("/otherwarrooturl");
```

Now you have you context and the other context, let us assume the target class is com.debora.MyClass

We are going to load the class using the other context

```
try {
     Class myclass = othercontext.loadClass("com.debora.MyClass");
     Field[] fields =  myclass.getDeclaredFields();
     //....your reflection program to fetch the static value...
     //....or using method invoke...
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    //your cleanup code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But the access to the httpRequest is not available in my case..

Comment: it is not HttpRequest, it is internal context sharing via java servlet codes only

Comment: If you are using jersey or spring mvc service functions or web method you can definitely get the HttpServletRequest variable instance via @Context annotation in your methods, otherwise you can directly declare an auto wire for ServlettContext in your class itself